# C++ Advice on manipulating output Matrix data

Tags: c++, matrix, output

I have the following code.
Essentially it is creating N random normal variables, and running through an equation M times for a simulation.

The output should be an NxM matrix of data, however the only way I could do the calculation has the output as MxN. ie each M run should be a column, not a row.
I have attempted in vain to follow some of the other suggestions that have been posted on previous similar topics.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    double T = 1; // End time period for simulation
    int N = 4; // Number of time steps
    int M = 2; // Number of simulations
    double x0 = 1.00; // Starting x value
    double mu = 0.00; // mu(x,t) value
    double sig = 1.00; // sigma(x,t) value
    double dt = T/N;
    double sqrt_dt = sqrt(dt);
    double** SDE_X = new double*[M]; // SDE Matrix setup
    // Random Number generation setup   
    double RAND_N;
    srand ((unsigned int) time(NULL)); // Generator loop reset
    std::default_random_engine generator (rand());
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (0.0,1.0); // Mean = 0.0, Variance = 1.0 ie Normal

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        SDE_X[i] = new double[N];

        for (int j=0; j < N; j++) 
            {
                RAND_N = distribution(generator);
                SDE_X[i][0] = x0;
                SDE_X[i][j+1] = SDE_X[i][j] + mu * dt + sig * RAND_N * sqrt_dt; // The SDE we wish to plot the path for

                std::cout << SDE_X[i][j] << " ";
            }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  The simulation is complete!!" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you link to the other questions you've looked at and explain specifically why their answers didn't solve your problem.

Comment: You have C++11 so why aren't you using a 2d vector to store your matrix? Why are you seeding the old rand to generate a random value to seed the new rand?

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2010. Don't think it is C++11 (completely). <chrono> is not recognised so as a workaround I went and seeded with rand(). as for the 2d vector... I will look to see If I can get it to work.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(M, std::vector<double>(N));`

Comment: Cheers Neil, I used your advice. Yes I am a noob.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well why can't you just create the transpose of your SDE_X matrix then? Isn't that what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that presentation has nothing to do with implementation. Whether to access columns or rows is your decision. So you want an implementation of it transposed. Then quick and dirty create your matrix first, and then create your number series. Change i and j, and N and M.

I said quick and dirty, because the program at all is bad:

1. why don't you just keep it simple and use a better data structure for your matrix? If you know the size: compile-time array or dynamic vectors at runtime? Maybe there are some nicer implementation for 2d array.
2. There is a bug I think: you create N doubles and access index 0 to N inclusive.
3. In every iteration you set index 0 to x0 what is also needless.

I would change your code a bit make more clear:

1. create your matrix at first
2. initialize the first value of the matrix
3. provide an algorithm function calculating a target cell taking the matrix and the parameters.
4. Go through each cell and invoke your function for that cell

Comment: Excellent advice. Thankyou. Will keep plugging away

Comment: Thanks Aitch. I went through my code. was able to sort it out with another for loop. The indexing from 0 to N inclusive is necessary for my needs.

Comment: then allocate N+1 doubles. If you write `new double[N]` you get N doubles from zero to N-1. you must not access item N!

Comment: Which particular part of my code are you talking about?

Comment: `SDE_X[i] = new double[N]; ... for (int j=0; j < N; j++)  { ... SDE_X[i][j+1] ...}`

Comment: well 7 hours ago it was :D is your problem solved now?

Comment: LOL yes thanks mate but if you have any advice on my new code pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. I was able to implement my code and have it displayed as needed. 
I added a second for loop to rearrange the matrix rows and columns.
Please feel free to let me know if you think there is anyway I can improve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    double T = 1; // End time period for simulation
    int N = 3; // Number of time steps
    int M = 2; // Number of simulations
    int X = 100; // Max number of matrix columns
    int Y = 100; // Max number of matrix rows
    double x0 = 1.00; // Starting x value
    double mu = 0.00; // mu(x,t) value
    double sig = 1.00; // sigma(x,t) value
    double dt = T/N;
    double sqrt_dt = sqrt(dt);

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> SDE_X((M*N), std::vector<double>((M*N))); // SDE Matrix setup

    // Random Number generation setup   
    double RAND_N;
    srand ((unsigned int) time(NULL)); // Generator loop reset
    std::default_random_engine generator (rand());
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (0.0,1.0); // Mean = 0.0, Variance = 1.0 ie Normal

    for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
    {
        SDE_X[i][0] = x0;

        for (int j=0; j <= N; j++) 
            {
                RAND_N = distribution(generator);
                SDE_X[i][j+1] = SDE_X[i][j] + mu * dt + sig * RAND_N * sqrt_dt; // The SDE we wish to plot the path for
            }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= N; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <=M; i++)
        {
            std::cout << SDE_X[i][j] << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  The simulation is complete!!" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```